# How do I read the specifications for this Panasonic microwave trim kit?

Tags: kitchens, trim, measurement

The [web page for the NN-TK922SS 27" Wide Trim Kit for select Panasonic Microwave Ovens](https://shop.panasonic.com/microwave-and-kitchen/microwave-ovens/microwave-oven-trim-kits/NN-TK922SS.html) includes these specifications:

```
TRIM KIT OUTER SIZE
Side A: 18-9/16"
Side B: 27"

TRIM KIT INNER SIZE
Side C: 24-5/8"
Side D: 13-7/16"

CABINET OPENING
Side E: 25-1/2"
Side F: 17-3/8"
Side G: 21" minimum
```

What is meant by Sides A, B, C, D, E, F, and G?

The cut-out in the plans for my cabinet is 25-1/2" wide and 15-5/16" high. I want to make sure that the trim will fit in/on the cabinet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the link you posted at the top of your question. Look at the frame pictures to the left. In the middle is a small picture. Click on it and it shows the a,b,c,d,e, etc.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Those are probably a reference to a diagram in the installation guide. They aren't industry standards that can be translated in the abstract. [See page 5](ftp://ftp.panasonic.com/accessory/microwaveoven/om/nn-tk932_732_922_722_en_om.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like page 5 only shows the outer dimensions (sides A and B).